# rename file in python

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to rename a file in a directory using Python.
I'm trying to change all the files with .tvx extension to .xml extension.
Here is what I tried:

```
for filename in os.listdir("."):
    if filename.endswith(".tvx"):
        os.rename(filename,filename[:-4]+'.xml')
```

For some weird reason - that doesn't work. 
Everything seems to work fine, the code exits with exit code 0, when I'm debugging the for loop I see the right .tvx files that I'm expecting, but when I check the folder - the name of the file still ends with .tvx!
any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried adding print statements to check what is going on.

Comment: Yes. I tried printing the filename var - and nothing seemed to be problematic.

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure you were doing `os.listdir(".")`, not some other directory?

Comment: Yes, and also the file names I'm getting are the file names in this directory.

Comment: Can you please share a snapshot of listing of your directory?

Comment: Any reason you're doing this with python, and not just using the Linux `rename` command?

Comment: So if you take out the loop and call `os.rename` with literal strings, does it have the same problem?

Comment: `rename 's/\.tvx$/.xml/' *.tvx`

Comment: Thanks barmar! the regex works!! I can't understand why my code didn't though...